Asymptotic of fourier transform of the probability distribution of a stochastic process with finite jump
I'm trying to model an ensemble of particle that constantly feel a viscous drag $\gamma$ and for which, at a exponential rate $\mu$, two of them gain a velocity $\delta$ and $-\delta$.
The evolution equation for the probability density of the velocity reads: $$\dfrac{\partial P(v)}{\partial t}=-\gamma\dfrac{\partial (v P(v))}{\partial v}+\mu\left(P(v-\delta)+P(v+\delta) - 2P(v)\right)\tag 1$$
The stationnary state is given by the 0 of this equation and the solution in Fourier space is given by:
$$0=\dfrac \gamma {2\mu} k\dfrac{\partial  \tilde P(k)}{\partial k}+P(k)\left(\cos(k\delta) - 1\right)\tag 2$$
which admits as a solution:
$$P(k) = e^{\dfrac{-\text{CosIntegral}(-\delta k)+\log(k)}{\gamma/(2\mu)}}\tag 3$$
Where $\text{CosIntegral}$ is the integral of $\cos(x)/x$. When the size of the jump is small, we can taylor expand the $\text{cosIntegral}$, it gives $P(k)\sim e^{-\beta k^2}$ and hence, we recover that $P(v)$ is gaussian, as expected in the limit of the continuous random walk. However, for finite $\delta$. It seems that we can obtain strongly non gaussian behavior as we can see in the (awful) simulations of this process for $\delta = 1$ and $\gamma/(2\mu) = 0.01$:

The issue is that, I cannot find an asymptotic solution to the inverse Fourier transform of the full $P(k)$ (3) at $v=0$ or $v=\infty$, especially for large $\gamma/2\mu$.
My question is:
Can we find an asymptotic solution $P(v)$ to (1) in the regime $v\sim 0$ or $v\sim\infty$?
Note that, I'm not too found of this model. I just want a system in which particles feel drag and experience discrete/strong jump. Perhaps an ornstein uhlenbeck process with levy jump would be also appropriate..
